# Get 7 day average for timeframe?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently running the following query to get the daily average of entries per user on my database, it's working as expected but I want to modify it to get the 7 day averages by day.

```
SELECT
    AVG(bg),
    AVG(carbs),
    timestamp
FROM users_entries
WHERE uid = '10b47fded7d2ea8d' AND
timestamp >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND timestamp <= '2019-01-30 00:00:00'
GROUP BY DAY(timestamp)
```

So for example, for the time frame, say `2019-01-01 00:00:00` to `2019-06-01 00:00:00` I would like to find all averages for 7 days and list them out. Basically take each day in the time frame, go back 7 days and get the average of the columns I select.

I'm thinking that this would require some sort of subquery but based on what I see online I do not understand them well enough to figure it out on my own, any help would be great.

Comment: Please include sample input and sample output. And `show create table` is also potentially helpful.

Comment: Are there entries in your table for *every* day?

Comment: @Nick There can be multiple entries per day or 0 per day, depends on what the user uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp),
       AVG(bg),
       AVG(carbs),
       AVG(AVG(bg)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE(timestamp) ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as bg_7,
       AVG(AVG(carbs)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE(timestamp) ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as bg_7,
FROM users_entries
WHERE uid = '10b47fded7d2ea8d' AND
      timestamp >= '2019-01-01' AND
      timestamp < '2019-01-30'
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp);
```

This is much more challenging in older versions of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, I believe updating my database is an option and am looking into it but would there be an alternative for mysql 5.7? I use a shared database instance for my smaller projects and would like to try to avoid updating it.

Comment: Upgraded my server and this is working... only thing is sequel pro doesn't work with mysql 8 but thats okay. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to get a deeper explanation of this query? It definitely is doing what I need but my understanding of it is lacking.